# rewrite htaccess on localhost using wamp server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I tried to rewrite `htaccess` for local server.

This is my local URL http://kiwitravel.localhost/index.php?var=home

I need something like this page: http://kiwitravel.localhost/index/home

I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your htaccess file? You said it doesn't work. What happens? Does it give a 500 error?

Comment: no.im not using framework.
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /var/(.*)/ index.php?var=$1

this is htacces.showign 5oo error

Answer (score -1):

Changing your htaccess file to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?var=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /index/%2\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ /index.php?var=$1 [L]
```

The above should change `http://kiwitravel.localhost/index.php?var=home` to `http://kiwitravel.localhost/index/home`

Comment: Do you have anything else in your htaccess file?

Comment: In the url bar, does it show the old url (`index.php?var=value`) or the new one (`index/value`)

Comment: still like index.php?var=value

Comment: And you only have the code above in your htaccess file and the file is in the same folder as the index.php is?

Comment: ya..htaccess and index file are same folder.